# While using Azure Managed service Identity, AKS, AAD and Key vault. Do all these resources need to be in the same subscription/Resource group or VNET

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azure-aks

Basically I have a setup where I have

- Hub-Spoke subscription and vnet topology in azure.
- AAD for internal users and developer access and b2c for external
  users.
- AAD and Keyvault are in HUB subscription/VNET.
- APIs which are deployed in Azure AKS clusters are in the spoke subscription.
- Also have API Management fronting the APIs which is in the same
  subscription and VNET as the AKS/APIs so in the Spoke subscription

Given the setup above, I have these questions

1. Do all the APIs, API management, Keyvault and Azure AD need to be 
   tied to the same subscription or can I have Keyvault in my hub
   subcription and other services in different subscriptions.
2. Do we register each API as an app in the same AAD as
   KEYVAULT or can we just register the API management and use API
   management to get the secrets.
3. Can we use managed service identity, even if the components are in
   different subscriptions but registered with the same Azure AD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication in Azure is done at a tenant level, so presuming you're not using the advanced services for Key Vault (ARM access, VM encryption etc) you can have your Key Vault in one subscription and access that from MSI in a difference subscription - as long as you grant that MSI user permissions to the key vault.

As long as you grant permissions to the resource, AAD has very little awareness of subscriptions (subscriptions are basically one big resource that you can grant privileges to)

Edited to clarify advanced access policies

There are three advanced access policies for key vault.

- enabledForDeployment
- enabledForDiskEncryption
- enabledForTemplateDeployment

the `enabledForTemplateDeployment` policy only applies if you are reading a secret from an ARM template deployment. i.e. if you are passing a VM password directly from Key vault.

For your situation, if this is a requirement, then you could simply have those being placed in a different key vault located in the same subscription.

Comment: We will be using ARM access( ARM deployments, if thats what you mean)

Comment: @PreetSingh I have updated the answer, hopefully, that clarifies.